# Convergence of $e^{ix_nt}$ implying convergence of $x_n$

Tags: periodic-functions, pointwise-convergence

Suppose $f_n:\mathbb{R} \to S^1$ are given by $f_n(t) = \mathrm e^{\mathrm i x_nt}$, where $x_n$ is some fixed real sequence.
It is clear that whenever $x_n$ converges, $f_n$ must converge to
$\mathrm e^{\mathrm i t \lim_{n\to \infty}x_n}$.

If $f_n$ converges pointwise to a continuous function, is it true that $x_n$ must converge?

Intuitively i think it is true, but i couldn't find a way to prove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your conjecture is true, and you can prove it without assuming the limit is continuous, and relaxing pointwise convergence to almost sure convergence on some open interval.

Call the limit $f$.

Case 1: $x_n$ is unbounded. For any interval $I$ we have $\int_I f=\int_I \lim f_n=\lim \int_I f_n=0$ by dominated convergence. Therefore $f=0$. This contradicts the fact that we don't have convergence in probability to $f=0$.

Case 2: $x_n$ is bounded. Then it has a convergent subsequence, with limit $x^*$. If this wasn't the limit of the original sequence, there'd be another subsequence limit $x_+$. Then you'd have $f_n$ converge to both $f_*$ and $f_+$, which contradicts the uniqueness of almost sure limits.

PS: you cannot relax your assumptions to convergence on $\mathbb{Q}$. In fact, enumerate the rationals as $q_n$ and pick $x_n$ such that $f_n(q_i)=1, i\leq n$.